# Make Tabs Stick To Top Of Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok so I'm working on a restaurant app design and want to be able to stick the tabs with the category names right below the "now serving breakfast" block then as you scroll down to the next category I would like it to replace the category name tab with the current one.

Similar to how Instagram have the username tab while scrolling down the newsfeed.

http://codeclimb.com/menus2/index2.html

Any ideas on what javascript can get this done?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [codepen](http://codepen.io/chrissp26/full/gBrdo)

Here is the code:

```js
function stickyTitles(stickies) {

    this.load = function() {
        
        stickies.each(function() {
            
            var thisSticky = jQuery(this).wrap('<div class="followWrap" />');
            thisSticky.parent().height(thisSticky.outerHeight());
            
            jQuery.data(thisSticky[0], 'pos', thisSticky.offset().top);
            
        });
    }
        
    this.scroll = function() {
    
        stickies.each(function(i) {
            
            var thisSticky = jQuery(this),
                nextSticky = stickies.eq(i+1),
                prevSticky = stickies.eq(i-1),
                pos = jQuery.data(thisSticky[0], 'pos');
        
            if (pos <= jQuery(window).scrollTop()+100) {
                
                thisSticky.addClass("fixed");
                
                if (nextSticky.length > 0 && thisSticky.offset().top >= jQuery.data(nextSticky[0], 'pos') - thisSticky.outerHeight()) {
                    
                    thisSticky.addClass("absolute").css("top", jQuery.data(nextSticky[0], 'pos') - thisSticky.outerHeight());

                }
                
            } else {
                
                thisSticky.removeClass("fixed");
                
                if (prevSticky.length > 0 && jQuery(window).scrollTop() <= jQuery.data(thisSticky[0], 'pos')  - prevSticky.outerHeight()) {
                
                    prevSticky.removeClass("absolute").removeAttr("style");
                
                }               
            }
        });         
    }
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    var newStickies = new stickyTitles(jQuery(".followMeBar"));
    
    newStickies.load();
        
    jQuery(window).on("scroll", function() {

        newStickies.scroll();
    
    }); 
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
.followMeBar {
  background: #222;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #111;
  border-top: solid 1px #444;
  padding: 1%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.followMeBar.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  width: 98%;
  z-index: 0;
}
.followMeBar.fixed.absolute {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="followMeBar">a</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="followMeBar">b</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="followMeBar">c</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="followMeBar">d</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="followMeBar">e</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="followMeBar">f</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="followMeBar">g</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="followMeBar">h</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="followMeBar">i</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="followMeBar">j</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="followMeBar">k</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="followMeBar">l</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="followMeBar">m</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="followMeBar">n</div>
```

I modified it a bit since I see your headers have some offset (I would change the `<br>`s for a margin top on your div with the content wrapper ids)

Comment: @Shelly *RE: your suggested edits... you are right formatting is important but please try to suggest more substantial edits than a single indentation level. For this answer in particular there is much more that you could have improved. Thanks.*

Comment: I did not quite understand you, but yeah just a quick copy/paste of a codepen code. What would you improve @Radiodef ? I think this code is quite good actually!

Comment: My comment was more directed towards a suggested editor. Anyway: see my edit. You could also consider removing some of the blank lines. Shorter/narrow is generally easier to read for a Stack Overflow post. (Less scrolling.)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the actual position of a drop down select menu is a function of the browser and cannot be directly changed.

Alternatively, have you looked at [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns)?

You can create a pretty slick dropdown, using this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form>
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

*update*
Forgot to add the scroll feature in bootstrap:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy

I believe this will accomplish what you are looking for.

There are a lot of other frameworks out there, but this one is great to start off with.